# Rails 4.2.10 upgrade TypeError: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, activesupport

I Just upgraded old rails app (3.2.22) to rails 4.2.10 and I am not sure if this is the right place but after a few hours of research, I am a little stumped. BRAND NEW rails 4.2.10 (same ruby) projects work (the behavior below does not happen) but this upgraded project fails on any instance of the ActiveSupport:: Duration functions. Did I miss something in the upgrade? Is it a gem issue? load order?

its not just Fixnum its any of these ActiveSupport::Duration functions

Expected behavior

```
irb(main):001:0> 20.days
=> 20 days
irb(main):002:0> 20.days.from_now
=> Wed, 13 Jun 2018 22:35:42 UTC +00:00
```

Actual behavior

```
irb(main):003:0> 20.days
TypeError: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Fixnum
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:35:in `*'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:35:in `days'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0> 20.days.from_now
TypeError: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Fixnum
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:35:in `*'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:35:in `days'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/ttsentsiper/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
System configuration
```

Rails version: 4.2.10

Ruby version: ruby 2.3.1p112

I also tried upgrading to ruby 2.4 on the same project and the issue persists (seems not ruby related)
Also copied the gemfile from the project that does not work into a new project and things seem ok

Comment: We're probably missing some context here. It looks like you're trying to use `20.days.from_now` (or whatever) in a situation where it shouldn't be. Can you share exactly how you're using this idiom?

Comment: I was using it in the rails console to test the various active support helpers. The failures in the project appear anywhere those functions are invoked (within third part gems that I did not write) (same error as you see in the console here)

Comment: Can you share the _Gemfile.lock_ for the project?

Comment: Maybe there are monkeypatches? Have you searched whole project for `.days`? Also gemfile would be helpful

Comment: @TimorTsentsiperdid you find the solution to this problem?